# How to make a variable unique?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to have the flight number variable unique. By unique, I mean it shouldn't be the same like another one that has been created before.

const flightSchema =  new Schema ({
FlightNumber: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
DepartureTime: {
type: Date,
required: true
}
}}

Comment: I have another question. What if I wanted the departure time to be before the arrival time?

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for such a constraint?

Comment: I know a way to do it, but im seeking for an easier one because I feel like i am complicating it.

Comment: Well the way this site works is you should show what you have tried and ask questions based on your own attempts to solve an issue. This is not a "how to" tutorial site. if you don't show what you tried then there is a good chance you will get the same thing as a solution which is a waste of everyone's time

Answer (score 1):

Add `unique: true`, like `FlightNumber: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }`

Comment: This helped, thanks. I have another question. What if I wanted the departure time to be before the arrival time?

Comment: @AliMassoud make another stackoverflow question; you're supposed to have one problem per question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `unique: true`, as advised in [the documentation](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/unique).